# Which is more efficient for initialising a property, null checking in an if or coalescence?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, null-coalescing

I have been working to make some code more efficient, and I am wondering now which pattern is the more efficient. The solution has code in both VB.NET and C# for legacy reasons.

I have put in the VB and C# versions of the two approaches that we have.

The idea is that if the `Foo` property is accessed and `_foo` is null, then it will be set to a new object, and any subsequent requests will access that same object and not create a new one each time.

I know that the compiler and JIT do some smart things under the bonnet, but I am not sure which is the more efficient way of doing things.

Option 1: Coalesce the value. Visual Studio keeps recommending coalescence in places, so this makes me think that that operation is quite optimised. However, this does assign to `_foo` each time we get `Foo`
Option 2: Do the comparison of `_foo` and `null` and then only assign to `_foo` if needed.

I'm sure that there is barely any difference between the two in speed, but I am curious about how these are treated at the much lower level

```vb
Private _foo As List(Of Fubar)
Private _bar As String
Private _foo2 As List(Of Fubar)
Private _bar2 As String

Public Property Foo As List(Of Fubar)
    Get
        _foo = If(_foo, New List(Of Fubar))
        Return _foo
    End Get
    Set (value As List(Of Fubar))
        _foo = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Bar As String
    Get
        _bar = If(_bar, String.Empty)
        Return _bar
    End Get
    Set (value As String)
        _bar = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Foo2 As List(Of Fubar)
    Get
        If _foo2 Is Nothing Then _foo2 = New List(Of Fubar)
        Return _foo2
    End Get
    Set (value As List(Of Fubar))
        _foo2 = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Bar2 As String
    Get
        If _bar2 Is Nothing Then _bar2 = String.Empty
        Return _bar2
    End Get
    Set (value As String)
        _bar2 = value
    End Set
End Property
```

```cs
    private List<Fubar> _foo;
    private string _bar;
    private List<Fubar> _foo2;
    private string _bar2;
    public List<Fubar> Foo
    {
        get
        {
            _foo = (_foo ?? new List<Fubar>());
            return _foo;
        }
        set
        {
            _foo = value;
        }
    }

    public string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            _bar = (_bar ?? string.Empty);
            return _bar;
        }
        set
        {
            _bar = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Fubar> Foo2
    {
        get
        {
            if (_foo2 == null) { _foo2 = new List<Fubar>(); }
            return _foo2;
        }
        set
        {
            _foo2 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Bar2
    {
        get
        {
            if (_bar2 == null) { _bar2 = string.Empty; }
            return _bar2;
        }
        set
        {
            _bar2 = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: _"I'm sure that there is barely any difference between the two in speed, but I am curious about how these are treated at the much lower level"_ - then decompile them and benchmark them. Also, there's option 3: `return _foo ?? (_foo = new List<Fubar>())`.

Comment: Allways good to read: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ Or on short: instead of making us **guess**, simply **measure** yourself.

Comment: I've put the code into an isolated project and put it through ILSpy to see if there was anything strange being done on build, but they came out the same as they went in.

I like Option 3 for the C# half, but I don't think it would work on the VB half?

Comment: I think none of them are thread safe.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Fair point, and if it is negligible then that's fine. However, I am aware of some patterns that on the face of it look like they should be ok but when you look at what they are actually doing, there is a marked difference in behaviour and memory usage between them. I am also making sure I am not falling into one of those traps

Comment: **[Guidelines for Collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections)** is worth reading

Comment: If this were real code, it's plausible that from the time the application is deployed until it's no longer used, the cumulative difference in execution time won't come close to how long it takes to figure out which is faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go; the `IsEmpty` here is telling us whether it was `null` before the `get` operation, i.e. which branch did it take.

My conclusion:

- if the value will usually have a value, the `*2` approach is better
- if the value will usually *not* yet have a value, there's no real difference
- but these times are unlikely to impact your application; both are very fast

Personally, in C# I prefer:

```cs
get => x ?? (x = val);
```

I'll add a timing for that... (edit: that is `Foo3`/`Bar3` and it looks to be a marginal improvement on `Foo2`/`Foo3`).

```
| Method |  Job | Runtime | IsEmpty |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |   Median |
|------- |----- |-------- |-------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|
|    Foo |  Clr |     Clr |   False | 1.764 ns | 0.0106 ns | 0.0094 ns | 1.760 ns |
|   Foo2 |  Clr |     Clr |   False | 1.175 ns | 0.0235 ns | 0.0305 ns | 1.185 ns |
|   Foo3 |  Clr |     Clr |   False | 1.165 ns | 0.0227 ns | 0.0347 ns | 1.180 ns |
|    Bar |  Clr |     Clr |   False | 1.957 ns | 0.0350 ns | 0.0293 ns | 1.940 ns |
|   Bar2 |  Clr |     Clr |   False | 1.197 ns | 0.0313 ns | 0.0348 ns | 1.190 ns |
|   Bar3 |  Clr |     Clr |   False | 1.165 ns | 0.0156 ns | 0.0146 ns | 1.170 ns |
|    Foo | Core |    Core |   False | 2.142 ns | 0.0237 ns | 0.0185 ns | 2.135 ns |
|   Foo2 | Core |    Core |   False | 1.172 ns | 0.0232 ns | 0.0524 ns | 1.170 ns |
|   Foo3 | Core |    Core |   False | 1.168 ns | 0.0221 ns | 0.0237 ns | 1.170 ns |
|    Bar | Core |    Core |   False | 2.063 ns | 0.0414 ns | 0.0580 ns | 2.040 ns |
|   Bar2 | Core |    Core |   False | 1.169 ns | 0.0235 ns | 0.0392 ns | 1.170 ns |
|   Bar3 | Core |    Core |   False | 1.151 ns | 0.0230 ns | 0.0379 ns | 1.150 ns |
|        |      |         |         |          |           |           |          |
|    Foo |  Clr |     Clr |    True | 1.767 ns | 0.0174 ns | 0.0154 ns | 1.760 ns |
|   Foo2 |  Clr |     Clr |    True | 1.791 ns | 0.0150 ns | 0.0141 ns | 1.790 ns |
|   Foo3 |  Clr |     Clr |    True | 1.784 ns | 0.0196 ns | 0.0174 ns | 1.780 ns |
|    Bar |  Clr |     Clr |    True | 1.767 ns | 0.0075 ns | 0.0063 ns | 1.770 ns |
|   Bar2 |  Clr |     Clr |    True | 1.784 ns | 0.0086 ns | 0.0067 ns | 1.780 ns |
|   Bar3 |  Clr |     Clr |    True | 1.775 ns | 0.0211 ns | 0.0176 ns | 1.780 ns |
|    Foo | Core |    Core |    True | 2.360 ns | 0.0650 ns | 0.1400 ns | 2.290 ns |
|   Foo2 | Core |    Core |    True | 2.553 ns | 0.0987 ns | 0.1754 ns | 2.450 ns |
|   Foo3 | Core |    Core |    True | 2.464 ns | 0.0649 ns | 0.1894 ns | 2.345 ns |
|    Bar | Core |    Core |    True | 1.697 ns | 0.0234 ns | 0.0183 ns | 1.690 ns |
|   Bar2 | Core |    Core |    True | 1.717 ns | 0.0349 ns | 0.0621 ns | 1.695 ns |
|   Bar3 | Core |    Core |    True | 1.647 ns | 0.0223 ns | 0.0198 ns | 1.640 ns |
```

Note I removed the actual `List<T>` creation to avoid overhead - it assigns to a static now.

Code:

```cs
using BenchmarkDotNet.Attributes;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Configs;
using BenchmarkDotNet.Running;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class Program
{
    static void Main() => BenchmarkRunner.Run<MyTest>();
}
[ClrJob, CoreJob]
[GroupBenchmarksBy(BenchmarkLogicalGroupRule.ByParams)]
public class MyTest
{
    [Params(false, true)]
    public bool IsEmpty { get; set; }
    const int OperationsPerInvoke = 10000;
    private readonly Blab[] blabs = Enumerable.Range(0, OperationsPerInvoke).Select(XmlExporterAttribute => new Blab()).ToArray();
    [IterationSetup]
    public void Reset()
    {
        if (IsEmpty)
        {
            foreach (var blab in blabs) blab.Reset();
        }
    }

    [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = OperationsPerInvoke)]
    public void Foo()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blabs.Length; i++) _ = blabs[i].Foo;
    }
    [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = OperationsPerInvoke)]
    public void Foo2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blabs.Length; i++) _ = blabs[i].Foo2;
    }
    [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = OperationsPerInvoke)]
    public void Foo3()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blabs.Length; i++) _ = blabs[i].Foo3;
    }
    [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = OperationsPerInvoke)]
    public void Bar()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blabs.Length; i++) _ = blabs[i].Bar;
    }
    [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = OperationsPerInvoke)]
    public void Bar2()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blabs.Length; i++) _ = blabs[i].Bar2;
    }
    [Benchmark(OperationsPerInvoke = OperationsPerInvoke)]
    public void Bar3()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blabs.Length; i++) _ = blabs[i].Bar3;
    }
}
public class Fubar { }
public class Blab
{
    static readonly List<Fubar> s_SharedList = new List<Fubar>();
    public void Reset()
    {
        _foo = _foo2 = _foo3 = null;
        _bar = _bar2 = _bar3 = null;
    }
    private List<Fubar> _foo, _foo2, _foo3;
    private string _bar, _bar2, _bar3;
    public List<Fubar> Foo
    {
        get
        {
            _foo = (_foo ?? s_SharedList);
            return _foo;
        }
        set
        {
            _foo = value;
        }
    }

    public string Bar
    {
        get
        {
            _bar = (_bar ?? string.Empty);
            return _bar;
        }
        set
        {
            _bar = value;
        }
    }

    public List<Fubar> Foo2
    {
        get
        {
            if (_foo2 == null) { _foo2 = s_SharedList; }
            return _foo2;
        }
        set
        {
            _foo2 = value;
        }
    }


    public List<Fubar> Foo3
    {
        get => _foo3 ?? (_foo3 = s_SharedList);
        set { _foo3 = value; }
    }

    public string Bar2
    {
        get
        {
            if (_bar2 == null) { _bar2 = string.Empty; }
            return _bar2;
        }
        set
        {
            _bar2 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Bar3
    {
        get => _bar3 ?? (_bar3 = string.Empty);
        set { _bar3 = value; }
    }
}
```